# how to write result to JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtextarea

I have question - how to write result/ DB Select to JTextArea. My JButton´s method is:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){



    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("Connection OK");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/filisng", "root", "passw");
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        result = statement.executeQuery("select * from `filisng`.`names`");

        while(result.next()){

            String nam = result.getString("Name");
            String surnam = result.getString("Surname");

            System.out.printf("Name: %s\tSurname: %s\t\n", Name, Surname);
        }
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){System.out.println("Class Not Found! " +ex);
    }catch(SQLException exception){
        System.out.println("SQL Error " + exception);
}

    }
```

If I use `System.out.printf("Name: %s\tSurname: %s\t\n", Name, Surname);`   - I see output in Console but, how to set Text to JTextArea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
textArea.append( String.format( "Name: %s\tSurname: %s\t\n", Name, Surname ));
```

See [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html#append%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: This won't work in case the OP wants to output all the results from set. You overwrite the textArea text each time. Use `append()` method instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! .... i used textArea.setText() and i thought that doesnt work (my last DB record is empty). Now  .append() shows all my records   :)

Comment: Thanks svz for its comment.